# Localization works in some Partial views and doesn't work in others.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to make my app to be availabe in 2 langauges and I followed this [guide](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx) to do so. I did so (2 resources, code in ExecuteCore and etc) my view consists of a layout and many partial view. but the localization works in some but not in the other, for example "Log on" is being displayed in french at the header of the page but, it's in english in the middle of the page, and they both have same location ( for example: MyProject.Resource.LogOn) where do you think the problem is?

Comment: Set a break point when the child action is executed and type `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` in the immediate window. I suspect that the culture is resetted for those.

Comment: isn't that global? how come it's set only in some parts during one request?

Comment: It's not global. It's for the current thread only. But I don't know how much of the MVC pipeline that it executes for partials.

Comment: Thanks for the idea man :) there was nothing wrong with config, I made a mistake somewhere that was not related, I forgot to write a piece of code somewhere, anyway I was frustrated. I wish you could write some reply to let me assign the bounties.

Comment: You whish is my command =)

Comment: I have now exactly the same issue. What was your problem at this time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

et a break point when the child action is executed and type CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture in the immediate window. I suspect that the culture is resetted for those